# In Flex, what's the difference between 'creationComplete' and 'addedToStage'?

Tags: apache-flex, google-analytics

I want to count (via google analytics) the times a pop-up is displayed to the user. Which event should I use to deduce that the pop-up is being displayed to the user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a new pop up is created every time you display one, it doesn't matter which one you use as both events will be fired upon creating. If you are reusing the same object, you should use `addedToStage` as `creationComplete` is dispatched only once per `UIComponent`.

- `creationComplete` is [dispatched](http://www.wietseveenstra.nl/blog/2007/02/understanding-the-flex-application-startup-event-order/) when the component, and all of its child components, and all of their children, and so on have been created, laid out, and are visible.
- `addedToStage` is dispatched when a display object is added to the on stage display list, either directly or through the addition of a sub tree in which the display object is contained.

So if you are reusing the same object, you will get an `addedToStage` every time you display it.

Answer (score 0):

Someone commented about not having to use both addedToStage and creationComplete (I needed 50 rep to respond so making a new post)

Looks like there is a case where you need to use both.  For instance, when you need to update something every time a view is visited and the view is displayed on a state change.  The first time the view is seen, it is the creationComplete event which fires.  Using addedToStage at this point runs the risk of a child component being null.  Consecutive times that the view is displayed, it will not dispatch creationComplete, only addedToStage

Comment: This has the beginnings of a good answer. Could you clean up the formatting and perhaps provide a code example?

Answer (score -1):

From my own testing, it looks like using either would work. But it would be nice to know which is the more 'correct' one to use, and just what the difference is between the two.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you are asking again, a question cannot be an answer

Answer (score -1):

The first **addedToStage** event occurs before **creationComplete** so if you need to access child components you'll need to use both.

Comment: Incorrect answer, no need to use two of them. If you want to access child components, you must use creationComplete. addedToStage wont give access to child elements so its waste to use it when you really need to access child elements.